# Non-trivial example of a variety with an action of a unipotent group?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

$
\renewcommand{\C}{{\mathbb C}}
\renewcommand{\R}{{\mathbb R}}
$
In the preprint [Taking quotient by a unipotent group induces a homotopy equivalence](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2105.04441)
we proved the following result:

> **Theorem.**
> Let $U$ be a unipotent group over $\C$ acting
> on an irreducible complex algebraic variety $X$.
> Assume that there exists a surjective morphism of complex algebraic varieties
> $\varphi\colon X\to Y$ whose fibres are orbits of $U$.
> If $X$ and $Y$ are smooth and all orbits of $U$ in $X$ have the same dimension,
> then the induced map on the $C^\infty$-manifolds of $\C$-points $X(\C)\to Y(\C)$ is a homotopy equivalence.
> Moreover, if $U$, $X$, $Y$, and $\varphi$ are defined over $\R$,
> then the induced map on the $C^\infty$-manifolds of $\R$-points $X(\R)\to Y(\R)$ is surjective
> and induces  homotopy equivalences on connected components.

Note that the assumption that all orbits of $U$ in $X$ have the same dimension
is equivalent to the assumption that the morphism $\varphi$ is smooth; see
[Ravi Vakil, "The Rising Sea. Foundations of Algebraic Geometry", Theorem 25.2.2 and Exercise 25.2.F(a)](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf).

The only examples for this theorem that I know are the following:

> **Trivial example 1.** $X=G$ is a connected algebraic $k$-group (where $k=\C$ or $k=\R$),
> $\ U\subset G$ is a unipotent $k$-subgroup, $Y=G/U$,
> $\ \varphi\colon G\to G/U$ is the quotient morphism.

> **Trivial example 2.** $G$ is a connected algebraic $k$-group (where $k=\C$ or $k=\R$),
> $U'\subset G$ is a unipotent $k$-subgroup, $N\subset U'$ is a normal $k$-subgroup of $U'$,
> $\ X=G/N$, $\ Y=G/U'=X/U$ where $U=U'/N$,
> $\varphi\colon G/N\to G/U'=X/U$ is the quotient morphism.

> **Question.**
> What is a nontrivial example of such $(U,X,Y,\varphi)$ ?